# problem related to arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega

first of all, I am not very good at English. if I have done a mistake during describe the problem apologize me. I want to combine both ultrasonic sensor code and mpu6050 sensor. can anyone tell me how to combine both codes in one code?

```
#include <Wire.h>
//I2C communication library for MPU6050
#include <I2Cdev.h>
//MPU6050 interfacing library
#include <MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h>
//Processing incoming serial data 
#include <CmdMessenger.h>
//Contain definition of maximum limits of various data type
#include <limits.h>

//Creating MPU6050 Object
MPU6050 mpu(0x68);
//Messenger object
CmdMessenger Messenger_Handler = CmdMessenger(Serial);

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//DMP options
//Set true if DMP init was successful
bool dmpReady = false;
//Holds actual interrupt status byte from MPU
uint8_t mpuIntStatus;
//return status after each device operation
uint8_t devStatus;
//Expected DMP paclet size
uint16_t packetSize;
//count of all bytes currently in FIFO
uint16_t fifoCount;
//FIFO storate buffer
uint8_t fifoBuffer[64];


#define OUTPUT_READABLE_QUATERNION
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//orientation/motion vars
Quaternion q;
VectorInt16 aa;
VectorInt16 aaReal;
VectorInt16 aaWorld;
VectorFloat gravity;

//Euler angle container
float euler[3];

//yaw/pitch/roll container and gravity vector
float ypr[3];




// ================================================================
// ===               INTERRUPT DETECTION ROUTINE                ===
// ================================================================

volatile bool mpuInterrupt = false;     // indicates whether MPU interrupt pin has gone high
void dmpDataReady() {
    mpuInterrupt = true;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Motor Pin definition
//Left Motor pins

#define A_1 3
#define B_1 4

//PWM 1 pin number
#define PWM_1 6


//Right Motor
#define A_2 4 
#define B_2 5

//PWM 2 pin number
#define PWM_2 5

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Ultrasonic pins definition
const int echo = 24, Trig = 23;
long duration, cm;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Motor speed from PC
//Motor left and right speed
float motor_left_speed = 0;
float motor_right_speed = 0;
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//Setup serial, encoders, ultrasonic, MPU6050 and Reset functions
void setup()
{

  //Init Serial port with 115200 baud rate
  Serial.begin(115200);  

  //Setup Motors
  SetupMotors();
  //Setup Ultrasonic
  SetupUltrasonic();  
  //Setup MPU 6050
  Setup_MPU6050();

  //Set up Messenger 
//  Messenger_Handler.attach(OnMssageCompleted);

}

void SetupMotors()
{

 //Left motor
 pinMode(A_1,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(B_1,OUTPUT); 


 //Right Motor
 pinMode(A_2,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(B_2,OUTPUT);  

}


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Setup UltrasonicsSensor() function
void SetupUltrasonic()
{
 pinMode(Trig, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(echo, INPUT); 

}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Setup MPU6050 function

void Setup_MPU6050()
{


    Wire.begin();
   // initialize device
    Serial.println("Initializing I2C devices...");
    mpu.initialize();

    // verify connection
    Serial.println("Testing device connections...");
    Serial.println(mpu.testConnection() ? "MPU6050 connection successful" : "MPU6050 connection failed");

    //Initialize DMP in MPU 6050
    Setup_MPU6050_DMP();


}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Setup MPU 6050 DMP
void Setup_MPU6050_DMP()
{

     //DMP Initialization

   devStatus = mpu.dmpInitialize();

   mpu.setXGyroOffset(220);
   mpu.setXGyroOffset(76);
   mpu.setXGyroOffset(-85); 
   mpu.setXGyroOffset(1788);  


   if(devStatus == 0){
         Serial.println(F("Enabling DMP..."));
        mpu.setDMPEnabled(true);
    //mpu.setDMPEnabled(true);

//    pinMode(PUSH2,INPUT_PULLUP);    
//    attachInterrupt(PUSH2, dmpDataReady, RISING);

    mpuIntStatus = mpu.getIntStatus();

    dmpReady = true;

    packetSize = mpu.dmpGetFIFOPacketSize();

   }else{

     ;
     }   
}


void loop() {

 //Read from Serial port
    Read_From_Serial();

    //Send ultrasonic values through serial port
    Update_Ultra_Sonic();

    //Send MPU 6050 values through serial port
    Update_MPU6050();


}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Read from Serial Function

void Read_From_Serial()

{
   while(Serial.available() > 0)
    {

       int data = Serial.read();
//       Messenger_Handler.process(data);


    } 

}

void Update_Ultra_Sonic()
{
  digitalWrite(Trig, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(Trig, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(Trig, LOW);
  // The echo pin is used to read the signal from the PING))): a HIGH
  // pulse whose duration is the time (in microseconds) from the sending
  // of the ping to the reception of its echo off of an object.
  duration = pulseIn(echo, HIGH);


  //Sending through serial port
  Serial.print("u");
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(cm);
  Serial.print("\n");

}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Update MPU6050

void Update_MPU6050()
{



  int16_t ax, ay, az;
  int16_t gx, gy, gz;

    ///Update values from DMP for getting rotation vector
    Update_MPU6050_DMP();


}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Update MPU6050 DMP functions

void Update_MPU6050_DMP()
{

 //DMP Processing
 // if programming failed, don't try to do anything
    if (!dmpReady) return;

     // wait for MPU interrupt or extra packet(s) available
    while (!mpuInterrupt && fifoCount < packetSize) {

        ;    

          }


// reset interrupt flag and get INT_STATUS byte
    mpuInterrupt = false;
    mpuIntStatus = mpu.getIntStatus();

    //get current FIFO count
    fifoCount = mpu.getFIFOCount();

    // check for overflow (this should never happen unless our code is too inefficient)
    if ((mpuIntStatus & 0x10) || fifoCount > 512) {
        // reset so we can continue cleanly
        mpu.resetFIFO();
    }



// otherwise, check for DMP data ready interrupt (this should happen frequently)
else if (mpuIntStatus & 0x02) {
        // wait for correct available data length, should be a VERY short wait
        while (fifoCount < packetSize) fifoCount = mpu.getFIFOCount();

        // read a packet from FIFO
        mpu.getFIFOBytes(fifoBuffer, packetSize);

        // track FIFO count here in case there is > 1 packet available
        // (this lets us immediately read more without waiting for an interrupt)
        fifoCount -= packetSize;

        #ifdef OUTPUT_READABLE_QUATERNION
            // display quaternion values in easy matrix form: w x y z
            mpu.dmpGetQuaternion(&q, fifoBuffer);


            Serial.print("i");Serial.print("\t");
            Serial.print(q.x); Serial.print("\t");
            Serial.print(q.y); Serial.print("\t");
            Serial.print(q.z); Serial.print("\t");
            Serial.print(q.w);
            Serial.print("\n");


        #endif

        #ifdef OUTPUT_READABLE_EULER
            // display Euler angles in degrees
            mpu.dmpGetQuaternion(&q, fifoBuffer);
            mpu.dmpGetEuler(euler, &q);
            Serial.print("euler\t");
            Serial.print(euler[0] * 180/M_PI);
            Serial.print("\t");
            Serial.print(euler[1] * 180/M_PI);
            Serial.print("\t");
            Serial.println(euler[2] * 180/M_PI);
        #endif

        #ifdef OUTPUT_READABLE_YAWPITCHROLL
            // display Euler angles in degrees
            mpu.dmpGetQuaternion(&q, fifoBuffer);
            mpu.dmpGetGravity(&gravity, &q);
            mpu.dmpGetYawPitchRoll(ypr, &q, &gravity);
            Serial.print("ypr\t");
            Serial.print(ypr[0] * 180/M_PI);
            Serial.print("\t");
            Serial.print(ypr[1] * 180/M_PI);
            Serial.print("\t");
            Serial.println(ypr[2] * 180/M_PI);
        #endif

        #ifdef OUTPUT_READABLE_REALACCEL
            // display real acceleration, adjusted to remove gravity
            mpu.dmpGetQuaternion(&q, fifoBuffer);
            mpu.dmpGetAccel(&aa, fifoBuffer);
            mpu.dmpGetGravity(&gravity, &q);
            mpu.dmpGetLinearAccel(&aaReal, &aa, &gravity);
            Serial.print("areal\t");
            Serial.print(aaReal.x);
            Serial.print("\t");
            Serial.print(aaReal.y);
            Serial.print("\t");
            Serial.println(aaReal.z);
        #endif

        #ifdef OUTPUT_READABLE_WORLDACCEL
            // display initial world-frame acceleration, adjusted to remove gravity
            // and rotated based on known orientation from quaternion
            mpu.dmpGetQuaternion(&q, fifoBuffer);
            mpu.dmpGetAccel(&aa, fifoBuffer);
            mpu.dmpGetGravity(&gravity, &q);
            mpu.dmpGetLinearAccel(&aaReal, &aa, &gravity);
            mpu.dmpGetLinearAccelInWorld(&aaWorld, &aaReal, &q);
            Serial.print("aworld\t");
            Serial.print(aaWorld.x);
            Serial.print("\t");
            Serial.print(aaWorld.y);
            Serial.print("\t");
            Serial.println(aaWorld.z);
        #endif

        #ifdef OUTPUT_TEAPOT
            // display quaternion values in InvenSense Teapot demo format:
            teapotPacket[2] = fifoBuffer[0];
            teapotPacket[3] = fifoBuffer[1];
            teapotPacket[4] = fifoBuffer[4];
            teapotPacket[5] = fifoBuffer[5];
            teapotPacket[6] = fifoBuffer[8];
            teapotPacket[7] = fifoBuffer[9];
            teapotPacket[8] = fifoBuffer[12];
            teapotPacket[9] = fifoBuffer[13];
            Serial.write(teapotPacket, 14);
            teapotPacket[11]++; // packetCount, loops at 0xFF on purpose
        #endif


    }


}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem with your combined code? And please format the code correctly by selecting it and click the `{}` button in the editors toolbar or press Ctrl+k

Comment: I want to read mpu6050 and ultrasonic sensor both. but it this is the error                       Initializing I2C devices...
Testing device connections...
MPU6050 connection successful
Enabling DMP...
u 0

Comment: Have you tried to get the ultrasonic Sensor to work alone to be sure, that it works correctly?

Comment: yes. it worked. when both sensor test individually it work.

Comment: How did you connect a 3.3v sensor to a 5v board?

Comment: mpu6050 gy-521 work with 5v

Comment: No, it does not. It has no level shifters for sda and scl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function `Update_Ultra_Sonic()` you do the measurement and save the result in the variable `duration`. Then you print the variable `cm`, but you haven't calculated the value for this variable yet. You have to calculate the number of cm from the echos `duration` and save the result in `cm`. When you don't do this, the variable stays at zero.